# How Does Dependency Parameter Injection Work in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you initialize a controller, service, factory in Angular, you pass in an anonymous function as the the second parameter in the following format:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $q){
});
```

How does Angular determine from the above that it needs to initialize an instance of `$scope`and `$q` for our new controller?

Does it grab the parameter names you pass in and find the corresponding objects from the Angular library?

Comment: It's all well written up in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the critical part of Injector ([**source**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/03726f7fbd5d71c0604b8dd40e97cb2fb0fb777f/src/auto/injector.js#L65)):

```
var ARROW_ARG = /^([^\(]+?)=>/;
var FN_ARGS = /^[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

function extractArgs(fn) {
  var fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, ''),
      args = fnText.match(ARROW_ARG) || fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
  return args;
}
```

As you see, the key is analyzing the function's source(returned by `Function.prototype.toString()`). First, all the comments are removed. It's necessary, as one can define a function like this:

```
function (el /* DOMElement */, b) {...}
```

Next, the meaningful parts are matched both against the arrow syntax (ES6) and the traditional one. Essentially, both patterns are matching all the things within the *first* pair of parentheses in the function source.

This code is used, among other things, in `annotate` function - filling up the `$inject` collection:

```
 argDecl = extractArgs(fn);
 forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg) {
    arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name) {
      $inject.push(name);
    });
 });
```

You also need to know that the Angular devs [recommend to avoid](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/guide/di#implicit-annotation) the shown approach (so called `Implicit Annotation`), as it's not compatible with minifiers/obfuscators without tools like `ng-annotate`.